# Convertir una lista de números entrecomillados en floats en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, revisión-de-código

Un pequeño algoritmo que convierte números en una cadena de caracteres y después lo suma es:

```
total= 0

cadena= "1.2,1.5,1.7"

for i in cadena.split(","):
    i= float(i)
    total+= i
print(total)
```

Ahora bien, supongamos que los números vienen individualmente entrecomillados de esta forma:

```
cadena= "1.2","1.5","1.7"
```

¿Cuál es el comando que debo utilizar para que cada número quede como float y después sumarlo utilizando el mismo for? Al emplear el código inicial para la última cadena obtengo el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Cualquier orientación será muy apreciada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cadena = "1.2","1.5","1.7"` es una tupla en realidad, es equivalente a `cadena = ("1.2","1.5","1.7")`.  Simplemente recorrela con un `for`y haz el casting:

```
cadena= "1.2","1.5","1.7"

for i in cadena:
    print(float(i))
```

Si quieres una tupla de floats usa un generador por compresión:

```
>>> cadena_f = tuple(float(i) for i in cadena)
>>> cadena_f
(1.2, 1.5, 1.7)
```

Comment: Tan sencillo que era y yo dándole vueltas... ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes dos enfoques para conseguir lo mismo:

```
# string o cadena
cadena= "1.2,1.5,1.7"
tuple(map(float,cadena.split(",")))

# tupla de strings
tupla= ("1.2","1.5","1.7")
tuple(map(float,tupla))
```

Cuyo resultado es:

```
Out[0]:(1.2,1.5,1.7)
```